# CKEditor in a ajax form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to use the same ckeditor replace several time in a ajax form:

```
 ... <textarea id="textareaId"></textarea> ...
```

And a javascript code

```
CKEDITOR.replace('textareaId');
$('#textareaId').val("first");
CKEDITOR.replace('textareaId');
$('#textareaId').val("second");
```

Can somepody know why id does not show "second" instead of "first" in the textarea with ckeditor? And how to get the correct value $('#textareaId').val()?
Thank you

Comment: `Id`s are to be unique, do not use the same `Id` on all your `textarea`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should force destroying instance before replace again.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['textareaId'];
if (editor) { 
    editor.destroy(true); 
}
CKEDITOR.replace('textareaId');
```

Answer (score 1):

`Id`s should be unique, so (I don't use CKEditor btw so no clue what this is trying to achieve but am explaining how ids should be used):

```
<textarea id="textareaId"></textarea>
<textarea id="textareaId2"></textarea> <!-- changed id -->

CKEDITOR.replace('textareaId');
$('#textareaId').val("first");
CKEDITOR.replace('textareaId2'); /* new id for text area */
$('#textareaId2').val("second");
```

Comment: It's no solution. I'm using an ajax form for creating and updating different items with a description.